# Using setState (Class components) as a beginner React developer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm asking a basic question but I'm a noob which couldn't even find the answer in google so please be gentle . I'm trying to use setstate and I have no idea why my state continue to be empty. Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Ball from './Ball'

class Lottery extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { nums : []};
        this.RenderNums = this.RenderNums.bind(this);
        this.RenderNums();
    }

    RenderNums(){
        let ballnum = this.props.ballnum;
        let maxnum = this.props. maxnum;
        let arrnums = Array.from({length: ballnum}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * maxnum) +1);
        console.log(arrnums);
        this.setState({nums : arrnums});
    }
```

I'm trying to put my random number array in the state, for that I'm calling a function in the constructor, but after npm start and looking at the dev tools my state nums is an empty array. The random numbers array is created just fine and being printed to the console. Someone can tell what am I doing wrong by looking at the code? If necessary I'll try to put it on codepen.

Comment: ok but I'm trying to make this code before I learn about the react life cycles functions. i would like to know why this code ain't working please

Comment: Please provide full component code or make a demo repository on https://codesandbox.io/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `setState` or any side effect in constructor, as mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your
> component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to
> this.state directly in the constructor

Instead, assign the initial state directly or use a dedicated lifecycle, you should try [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

```
class Lottery extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nums: Array.from(
        { length: this.props.ballnum },
        () => Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.maxnum) + 1
      ),
    };
  }

  // or
  RenderNums = () => {...}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.RenderNums();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Instead of calling setstate in the constructor I changed the code as shown in the edit and it worked. Without did mounted though

Answer (score 1):

Put `this.RenderNums();` call inside `componentDidMount () {}` method.

```
class Lottery extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { nums : []};
    this.RenderNums = this.RenderNums.bind(this);
    //this.RenderNums();
}

componentDidMount(){
   this.RenderNums();
}

RenderNums(){
    let ballnum = this.props.ballnum;
    let maxnum = this.props. maxnum;
    let arrnums = Array.from({length: ballnum}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * maxnum) +1);
    console.log(arrnums);
    this.setState({nums : arrnums});
}
```

componentDidMount is equivalents useEffect in function components. you should not call setState inside Constructor.

Comment: Instead of didmount function I just called the function to create the random array inside the constructor instead of setState. Is that ok?